# WPF control origin point

Tags: wpf, xaml

After some investigation, I still can't find method to change origin of control.
So, I want just to place one square exactly in center of another square, without margins, so it will be completely independent of first square size.

Theoretically, it can be easily done with `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Center`, since it automatically sets `Margin` of control to half of width and height of parent control. But it is not so simple.
Simplest way to describe problem is next picture[image: Example]

As you can see, margin is counted towards upper left corner. Which is what I call origin. The perfect solution is to change it to center of first square, but this is where I need help - *how can I do that*?

Comment: can you show some code or xaml that illustrates the problem?  Is margin of inner square = 0?

Comment: @Sam, I can't use margins, since they are dependent on difference between squares size. I want to find the way to make square of any size be placed right inside of center of another square, using only xaml tools. I will provide example code ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was weird enough. The given behaviour can be seen only when using `Image`, and `Center` alignment. Can be solved by either wrapping `Image` in `Grid`, which will be using `Center` alignment, or using `Stretch` alignment with `Image` (which is much simplier).

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="500">
    <Image Width="250" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want to reproduce problem I've described in question, replace `Stretch` with `Center` in code above.

Comment: this is grasping at straws but try explicitly setting margin, border width, padding, to zero

Comment: Code above is actual solution, so i don't need any workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Point of origin applies when using a transform object, and attaching the transform to your control. It won't actually effect the behaviour of the margin or left, top properties. If using a transform to place your object, point of origin is very useful.

The top, left (if using cavas) and margin (if using say grid) help govern the "auto" placement by the parent control, and this in turn governs where point of origin for the control winds up being relative to the parent control. The transform object then offsets RELATIVE to where that point of origin is.

The other useful thing is that transform overrides the auto placement in the parent control, or rather, forces an offset to where the parent wants to put it, which in some cases is useful - i.e., you might have boxes listed in a grid and want them to "shake" left and right when you hover the mouse over them, their alignment stays in order to the grid, but the transform lets you bump them away from their "forced" position.

For example, attach the same transform object to 2 controls, and set their origins separate, then apply an animation to the transform object - both controls will animate off the one animation object (if you wanted to their movement in perfect sync).

Answer (score 0):

Probably oversimplifying here but I would just use a Grid to wrap the two items you mentioned like this example (One stretched to fit and one centered):

```
<Grid>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Margin="4"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10">InnerButton</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to place both controls in center of another control, as answer for question "How to place control in center of another control"? Sorry, but it sounds like "to get some iron, get yourself iron pickaxe, and dig some iron with it".

Comment: :-) Just a piece of lateral thinking to achieve what you appeared to want. Often its easier to use a grid to organise control placement and use the order of the controls in the XAML to make something appear to be in something else - rather than actually put something in something else. If you are adamant that one has to be in the other then just ignore the answer - just trying to help (or not as in this case - but I guess I misunderstood your original intention!)